# Nearby Connections Advertise method

Tags: google-nearby

Does the Nearby Connections API advertise through Wifi and Bluetooth, or just Bluetooth? My experimentation with the API shows that I can't find any device beyond ~30 meters which makes me think that it's using Bluetooth.

I know that the Cluster strategy is Bluetooth only, but if the strategy is set to Star, will the API use wifi for advertise?

Answer (score 2):

As of today, all 3 strategies (CLUSTER, STAR, POINT_TO_POINT) only use Bluetooth for advertising and discovery.

No promises that this will always be the case. More technologies (like WiFi) may be added in the future.

Comment: There is documentation that suggests high-frequency audio is used somehow as well.  Is this with Nearby Connections?  Is it used for advertising/discovery?

Comment: Currently audio is only used in Nearby Messages. There has been talk about adding it to Connections eventually, but you can only send a couple bytes over it (which is much shorter than our supported Endpoint name length), so it would have to be used for ranging rather than data transmission.